# Re Order Editor to be after meta box

Tags: editor, metabox

I want to reorder stuff in a custom post. I got the meta box and editor working together, but currently the editor is above the meta box
and I need it to be the other way around.

This is the code for my meta box:

```
// adding the meta boxes
add_action("admin_init", "tl_admin_init");
function tl_admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("testimonial_description-meta", __('Testimonial Description', 'sagive'), "testimonial_description", "testimonial", "normal", "core");
}


// getting, setting and displaying PROJECT DESCRIPTION meta box
function testimonial_description() {
    global $post; // this is a must!
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID); // this is a must!
    $testimonial_description = $custom["testimonial_description"][0];
    ?>
    <textarea name="testimonial_description" style="width: 98%; height: 10em; " /><?php echo $testimonial_description; ?></textarea>
    <label><?php _e('Write a Simple 2 Line Description of your client testimonial without html for clean design.', 'sagive'); ?></label>
    <?php
}
```

I tried removing the editor and re-instating after this function
but I guess that`s an over simplistic solution since it doesn't work.

I've removed the editor using this:

```
/* This will help me get rid of the editor */
function tl_remove_pages_editor(){
    remove_post_type_support( 'testimonial', 'editor' );
}   
add_action( 'init', 'tl_remove_pages_editor' );
```

Then added it again using `add_post_type_supports`.

Any suggestions anyone ?

Comment: -1 for the rollback. No meaning was lost, and readability was improved, see no reason to have rolled back the question.

Comment: you just went on my answers - answer by answer one at a time and changed them -** but only one char.. ** thats not nice.. i understand you like those badges man but comeon.. Then.. you went and -1 all my answers?  - i dont mean to be rude but thats acting like a child.. i could have done the same but i dont really care enough :) - just didnt understand why you acted like that.. you seem like a guy that helps - whatever..

Comment: What???.. I make edits to anyone and everyone's answers or questions(that's how Stack Exchange sites operate), i don't go about making edits to just your answers, despite whatever you may think i'm not giving you any special treatment.

Comment: this is probably what you're looking for :-)

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38562/how-to-customize-default-wordpress-editor/48754

Comment: Another very similar question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36600/how-can-i-put-a-custom-meta-box-above-the-editor-but-below-the-title-section-on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will allow the post editor to be moved like the other sortable post boxes.

```
function move_posteditor( $hook ) {
    if ( $hook == 'post.php' OR $hook == 'post-new.php' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts', 'move_posteditor_scripts');

    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'move_posteditor', 10, 1 );

function move_posteditor_scripts() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#postdiv, #postdivrich').prependTo('#your_meta_box_id .inside' );
</script>
<?php }
```

Comment: 10x a lot man.. it took a little tingeling to work with my custom post type but that did the trick - you the man!  :)

Comment: This is a pretty evil hack but it does work well, remember to change #your_meta_box_id to the name of the metabox you created with: add_meta_box("your_meta_box_id", "Editor Title", array(&$this, "editor"), "your_post_type", "normal", "core");

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest method I have found.

When creating your metabox, simply set the context to "advanced".  Then, latch on to the `edit_form_after_title` hook - print your meta boxes out there, then remove it so it doesn't appear twice.

```
// Move all "advanced" metaboxes above the default editor
add_action('edit_form_after_title', function() {
    global $post, $wp_meta_boxes;
    do_meta_boxes(get_current_screen(), 'advanced', $post);
    unset($wp_meta_boxes[get_post_type($post)]['advanced']);
});
```

Thanks to [Andrew's solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88103/48885).

Comment: I like this one the best.  Least amount of code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This solution from [WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/move-custom-meta-box-above-editor?replies=11#post-2721019) worked perfectly for me and without any JS.  I modified it to only target a single CPT, so in the code below replace `{post-type}` with the post type you want to target: `post`, `page`, `my_custom_post_type`, etc... (If that's confusing see the referenced link to .org for that standard page/post example)

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'jb_make_wp_editor_movable', 0 );
function jb_make_wp_editor_movable() {
    global $_wp_post_type_features;
    if (isset($_wp_post_type_features['{post-type}']['editor']) && $_wp_post_type_features['{post-type}']['editor']) {
        unset($_wp_post_type_features['{post-type}']['editor']);
        add_meta_box(
            'description_sectionid',
            __('Description'),
            'jb_inner_custom_box',
            '{post-type}', 'normal', 'high'
        );
    }
}
function jb_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
    the_editor($post->post_content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set `$priority` to `high` and change context?

If this is not helping - there is a hack you could use - which is to MOVE the editor INSIDE a meta-box and then you can place it as you like.